# NullPointerException create own JSON response object

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, nullpointerexception

As I started to work with Spring REST Services I came across with NullPointerExceptions and their responses.

Due to some missing details/information I get from the NullPointerException (as a Client), I would like to create an own JSON Object which will be sent after each NullPointerException I get.

Is there any way to override the body of the NullPointerException ResponseEntity?

Thanks for your time ;)

Comment: Can you please post the part of code which causes NullPointerException?

Comment: What is your end goal? Usually the reason is kept internally. There is no reason to send it to the client. Just act on the normal HTTP 500 code and display "internal error" or something else. You can relay the information to a mail or logging tool for bug reporting.

Comment: If using spring boot, search the reference documentation for the properties server.error.include-exception and server.error.include-stacktrace. Otherwise, look for ControllerAdvice in the Spring-MVC documentation.

Comment: My end goal is to send an own JSON object to an other backend service as soon as I get the NullPointerException. This JSON object should have the values of:
- status
- detail (with my own message)
- an own ID (something I want to add to the JSON object)
etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ControllerAdvice` for this. It can catch exceptions from the `Controller` beans and handle them.

In your case:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(NullPointerException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<OwnError> handleGenericError(final NullPointerException exception) {

        OwnError ownError=new OwnError();
        ownError.set...

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(ownError);
    }
}
```

This will return `OwnError` if your your `Controller` throws `NullPointerException`.